# How to generate new data values?

Tags: classification

I would like to perform classification for a medical data however one class has very few number of instance, I want to generate new data for this class by using the properties of the existing data.

Comment: What is your purpose? If this is how you would like to produce "more data to learn on", then notice that you will learn from the data that *you* created given some assumptions, so your algorithm will learn about your *assumptions* about the data rather then about properties of the data itself.

Comment: Why not using missing data imputation (eg mice package in R)?

Comment: It sounds as if the problem is not missing data, but too few data. One answer is all too simple and unwelcome: if you have only two kangaroos in the zoo and want some more, you need to go out and get them. Either way, more detail on your exact situation would help.

Comment: thanks for your responses, the purpose is binary data classification with unbalance classes; it is not a missing data problem. I am wondering,  does the distribution of the given data can help in generating new data. thanks

Comment: Is there any valid approach to generate new training data out of some existing training data?

Answer (score 0):

As Nick Cox implied in his comment, I think the only general answer is "no, you have to get more data".

Simulating data based on the actual data can be very useful for missing data issues, but that is not your problem and I don't think it helps you here. That sort of simulation (usually called imputation) uses the data that you do have on the actual subjects. So, for instance, you might impute blood pressure based on age, sex, weight and so on.

But you can't just make up new data. Sorry.

There may be some specific cases where a better answer is possible (although I can't think of any, offhand) but not in the general case.